# Installing local jar to automated pipeline and sonarqube: how to do it with no command and no systempath?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am developing a project which needs a client personal jar, and it needs to be deployed on a pipeline of tools which are out of our control (sadly). One of the tools in this pipeline is sonarqube.
To build and deploy we have to use maven.

I put the jar into a folder of the project, and tried various way to actually make it work.
The first (working) way was to have it as a system with a systemPath to the folder of the project. It compiled, worked and everything, but sonarqube apparently hates systemPath and made us take it away.
After a tiny bit of searching, we added to our pom a maven-install-plugin, bounded an install-file to validate phase and configured to generate the dependency. This seems to work on local if I first run mvn validate and THEN mvn clean package. Otherwise, it tries to look for the jar on the main repository and fails. If I comment the  tag and leave only the plugin active, I noticed it executes the plugin, installs the jar to local repository, but build fails due to not resolving packages and classes inside the jar. If I now put the  tag in, everything works, because it now find the jar in the repository.
While this solution works, it doesnt suite me because the repository will be emptied every once in a while, and to restart everything I would need to commits, one knownligly failing, just to install the jar.

I tried addind a  tag instead, pointing to a project dir where I would store the necessary jar, and that works just fine on my PC, but utterly fails on the pipeline, looking at main repository only (I guess it is some configuration on the pipeline, but cant really tell, being outside my control)

Comment: Why not put the jar into the main repository?

Comment: the main repository is handled by the same organization as the toolchain, we have to use it per client request, but we cant (at least in the forseeable future) ask for direct modifications.

Comment: Also the client doesnt want the jar to be on a public repository because it contains its own Auth mechanics (we have no actual idea how it works)

Comment: Don't you have a company internal Maven repository?

Comment: We have, we can use it on tests build, problem is in final deploy

Comment: Why can't you put your jar into the company internal Maven repository and reference it from there? Then you do not have to put it into project folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually able to do it with maven install plugin,

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <groupId>com.exmaple.stuff</groupId>
                <artifactId>ClientJar</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ClientJar-1.0.jar</file>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-client-jar</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And having dependency

```
<!-- Client jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>example</groupId>
        <artifactId>ClientJar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you notice, the tricky part here was actually that groupId is different between the dependency and the plugin declaration. I do not know if this difference is due to the configuration of their artifactory server, but it seems to work locally too.
Also it is needed to explicitly run mvn validate in the pipeline